# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable - issue

Tags: python-3.x

I keep getting a type error. It prints it right the first time around then can't print the second round.

I tried changing things but just got more errors

```
class reflex_vacuum():

  global count


  def count(pos, l, r):
    global count
    global p 
    global left
    global right
    p = pos
    left = l 
    right = r 


    count = 0 

    def clean(pos, l, r):
      global p 
      global left
      global right

      if pos == 'left':
        if l == 1:
          l=0
        pos = 'right'

      else:
        if r == 1:
          r=0
        pos = 'left'
      p = pos
      left = l 
      right = r  

    while left==1 or right==1:
      clean(p, left, right)
      count=count+1 
    print (count)

  def scale(sum):
    global count
    s = 10 - (count/sum)
    print ('The score is ' + str(s) + ' out of 10.')


  print('This program checks the efficiency of the vacuum depending on the vacuum position and dirt placement. The scale is 10 points. each move deducts a point. If move was made with dirt on both sides (thus move was necessary) then the move count is divided by two. \n')    
  print('Starting left with no dirt')
  count('left', 0, 0)
  scale(2)

  print('\nStarting right with no dirt')
  count('right', 0, 0)
  scale(1)

  print('\nStarting left with dirt left')
  count('left', 1, 0)
  scale(1)
```

I just need it to give me output for different combinations

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using the same name for two different types of things. You have a global variable named 'count' which stores an integer, and you have a class method named 'count'. On line 48, the first time you call `count("left", 0, 0)` the interpreter resolves that symbol to the method `count()`, as it is the only definition for `count` that exists. During the execution of that method, you do `count=count+1`, and this overwrites the symbol, changing it from a method to an integer. Then, after `count("left", 0, 0)` returns, you attempt to call `count("right", 0, 0)`, but now the global symbol `count` is no longer a method, it is an integer, and you are unable to call it as a method. This results in the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 1, in <module>
    class reflex_vacuum():
  File "tmp.py", line 53, in reflex_vacuum
    count('right', 0, 0)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Tracebacks are very valuable things. By running your code and seeing this, I was able to immediately see what it was attempting to do when it threw the error, and that informed me that the interpreter thought `count` was an integer, even though you have a method named `count`

So how do you solve this? Well there's a couple of options. The easiest one is to rename either the method `count()` or the global variable `count` so they do not share the same name.

However, I would urge you to spend some time learning about proper scoping of python variables and classes so that you do not need to use the `global` keyword at all. It is actually possible to have both a method named count and a variable named count like this, but not if you use `global` to tie them together.